# Виджет для отображения всех окон PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qstackedwidget

Скажите, какой есть в PyQt5 виджет, который бы на верху в окне показывал список всех окон (как кнопки, на фото это "первое окно" и "второе окно") и при нажатии на это окно, оно открывалось. Открывалось не в новом окне, а в этом же:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`QAction` в этом варианте не подойдет, оно открывает новое окно при нажатии (то есть теперь активно два окна), а нужно, чтобы отображалось всё на одном окне, чтобы можно было переключаться таким способом неограниченное кол-во раз.

Comment: Класс `QStackedWidget` предоставляет стек виджетов, в котором одновременно виден только один виджет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс `QStackedWidge`t предоставляет стек виджетов, в котором одновременно виден только один виджет.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *
 

class StackedExample(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(StackedExample, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('StackedWidget demo')
        
        self.leftlist = QListWidget()
        self.leftlist.currentRowChanged.connect(self.display)
        self.leftlist.insertItem (0, 'Contact'     )
        self.leftlist.insertItem (1, 'Personal'    )
        self.leftlist.insertItem (2, 'Educational' )
        
        self.stack1 = QWidget()
        self.stack2 = QWidget()
        self.stack3 = QWidget()
        
        self.stack1UI()
        self.stack2UI()
        self.stack3UI()
        
        self.stackWidget = QStackedWidget(self)
        self.stackWidget.addWidget(self.stack1)
        self.stackWidget.addWidget(self.stack2)
        self.stackWidget.addWidget(self.stack3)
        
        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        hbox.addWidget(self.leftlist)
        hbox.addWidget(self.stackWidget)
        self.setLayout(hbox)
       
        self.stackWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
       
    def stack1UI(self):
        layout = QFormLayout()
        layout.addRow("Name",    QLineEdit())
        layout.addRow("Address", QLineEdit())
        #self.setTabText(0,"Contact Details")
        self.stack1.setLayout(layout)
        
    def stack2UI(self):
        layout = QFormLayout()
        sex    = QHBoxLayout()
        sex.addWidget(QRadioButton("Male"))
        sex.addWidget(QRadioButton("Female"))
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Sex"),sex)
        layout.addRow("Date of Birth",QLineEdit())
        self.stack2.setLayout(layout)
        
    def stack3UI(self):
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(QLabel("subjects"))
        layout.addWidget(QCheckBox("Physics"))
        layout.addWidget(QCheckBox("Maths"))
        self.stack3.setLayout(layout)
        
    def display(self, i):
        self.stackWidget.setCurrentIndex(i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex  = StackedExample()
    ex.resize(100, 100)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]